# How do I get exchange rates by date?

Tags: java, currency, rates

I am interested to find exchange rates by a certain date. Do you guys know what API I can use for this? (Preferably, a free API.)

I create an object with creation date the *20th of May, 2016*. That object has a price in EUR. I want to be able to get the exchange rate of EUR to USD for that date and convert it to USD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `fixer.io` should suit your needs:

http://fixer.io/

Your example:

http://api.fixer.io/2016-05-20?base=EUR&symbols=USD

Note that apparently your referrer header can make you get a `403` response. (so copy and paste this link in the browser, don't click on it - thanks @Arnauld)

Comment: You may have to copy/paste the provided example link in the address bar of your browser in order to test it. A direct click results in a 403 / forbidden (probably because of the referrer). At least it does for me.

Comment: @Arnauld: you are right, sorry for that. Weirdly enough the HTTP link works fine.

Comment: @Arnauld: actualy that doesn't work either, the answer was cachhed.

Comment: Your example works @mszymborski. Arnauld was right, copying the link works. Thank you for the assist